# как прикрутить к сайту иконки?

Tags: html, css

есть иконочный шрифт awesome, есть скрипт, который должен вызываться посредством нажатия на кнопку(пусть это будет отправка данных о пользователе).
нужно, что бы при наведении на иконку ее цвет менялся
как это сделать

я так понимаю, что можно в тег `a` или `button` засунуть иконку, но как это делается?

(сами иконки пока что реализованы так. как сделать их с помощью шрифта я не разобрался. скрипта пока тож нет)

```
.user-btns-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 15%;
}
.user-btns-container .user-btn {
  background: no-repeat;
  width: 41px;
  height: 41px;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @splash58 , исправил

Answer (score 0):

https://w3schoolsrus.github.io/html/index.html зайди в раздел символы и скопируй символ
Если хочешь добавить иконку в а или button то в теге напиши скопированный символ и вставь или эмодзи они на том сайте тоже есть или картинку в сам тег с помощью тега img или bakcground url

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).